# Scrapy - Extracting specific data via CSS query doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to implement a super simple scraper that scrapes apartment prices and square footage from a website. I use Python + scrapy to implement that and only have one issue: It seems that the section were the needed info is, appears empty when returned as a response and everything that it contains (divs, spans, etc.) can also not be addressed via CSS query. I can access everything else besides the content in this section.

This is the website: https://www.251brandon.com/floorplans

This is how my preliminary spider looks (in this example just looking for the class "fp-price"):

```
import scrapy

class Brandon251Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "Brandon251"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        "https://www.251brandon.com/floorplans"
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    price = response.css('.fp-price').extract()

    yield {
        'test': price
    }
```

The return is an empty SectorList instead of all the elements that have the fp-price class.

[image: CSS structure of website]

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Take a look at the page source (instead of inspecting). You'll see that the page is constructed through javascript and therefore the scraper is not able to extract this data through a CSS selector as specified in your spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using xpath instead of selector:
`response.xpath('//*[@id="floorplan"]/text()')`

also have a look at: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

if @Casper is right, and the specific element is loaded by javascript, you should check out scrapy-splash (https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) this will enable you to load javascript and scrape the page afterwards. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. It was indeed a problem with dynamically generated content via javascript. Scrapy's build in "browser" only returns raw html code without executing the javascript. Using splash and the plugin scrapy-splash worked!
Here is a good and short video that helped me to add scrapy-splash:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvFC93vAB7U

Answer (score 0):

@Casper is correct the page is generated using Javascript. If you try to load the page in the browser with javascript disabled then the content is not made visible. However as is often the case when a page is loaded by javascript the data you want is in JSON.
I searched the network responses for one of the values of sqr ft and found that the data is all loaded with the page in a variable called pageData.

If you search the source of the page you find that a JSON object is defined with the page's data ready to build the page.

```
var pageData = {
  filters: {
    beds: [],
    baths: 0,
    priceRange: {
  low: 0,
  high: 9999
},
sqftRange: {
  low: 0,
  high: 9999
},
availableDate: "all",
amenities: []
  },
  hasImages: true,
  amenities: {
am_0: "Built in USB Ports",
am_1: "Designer Carpeting and Two-Tone Paint",
am_2: "Dishwasher",
am_3: "Double Stainless Steel Sinks",
am_4: "Gas Range",
am_5: "Granite Countertops",
am_6: "Large Patio Or Balcony",
am_7: "Linen Closet",
am_8: "Platinum Silver Kitchen Appliances",
am_9: "Pre-Wired For Technology",
am_10: "Spacious Closets",
am_11: "Stackable Washer/Dryer",
am_12: "Wood Blinds"
  },
  floorplans: [
    {
  id: 2029996,
  name: "1 Bed 1 Bath | 1B",
  amenities: [],
  sqft: 594,
  beds: 1,
  baths: 1.0,
  lowPrice: 2392,
  highPrice: 4208,
  availableCount: 1,
  availableDate: "10/8/2018",
  special: false,
  images: [
    {
      src: "/dmslivecafe/3/234323/1B.png?quality=85",
      alt: "",
      title: "1 Bed 1 Bath | 1B",
      caption: ""
    }
  ],
```